# Adding rectangles to a list via a for loop and then drawing them to the screen

Tags: c#, list, xna

I am building a basic clone of breakout using C# and XNA. All the code seems to be working well except when trying to create and draw the blocks to the screen.

In the LoadContent() method I used a for loop I tried to add 10 rectangles to a rectangle list (just for testing) with changing X and Y values.

```
int xChange = 0;
int yChange = 0;
//loop iterates 10 times as a test
for (int i = 0; i == 10; i++)
{
    rectList.Add(new Rectangle(100+xChange, 200+ yChange, 40, 80));
    xChange += 100;
    yChange += 50;
}
```

Then in the draw method I used a foreach loop to draw each of these:

```
foreach (Rectangle rect in rectList)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(block, rect,  Color.White);
}
```

When I run this code nothing draws and I'm not sure why. Full code can be found at http://pastebin.com/TNbzgUqn.

EDIT: By adding a rectangle manually (not in a loop) I got a rectangle to draw. This narrows it down to the for loop in which the rectangles are added to the list.

```
//The code below draws, the code above does not
Rectangle test1 = new Rectangle(200, 200, 40, 80);
rectList.Add(test1);
```

Comment: Where is rectlist declared?

Comment: If I had to guess, you drew those rectangles to the spritebatch but never drew the batch out to screen. That is a wild guess. I do not see a specific draw call, drawing the spritebatch. All I see is .End() being called.

Comment: Apparently End() is what you do at least from what I can see on MSDN. Maybe you have not set up the options correctly in the batch to have it output to your screen. Or maybe you are drawing off in something you cannot see. Verify your parameters

Comment: @DeanKnight rectList is declared in the base of the class (along with other rectangles and textures which work) so that isn't the problem. I checked the parameters and it should be drawing on the screen at a visible size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN:

By using a for loop, you can run a statement or a block of statements repeatedly until a specified expression evaluates to false.

Your for loop is saying: starting from 0, do the following while i is equal to 10. Which will always be false.
You should instead use:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
 // your code here
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :) also note that putting i <= 10, the loop will cycle 11 times (from 0 to 10), while using i < 10 will run 10 times (from 0 to 9).